# Accessing another phone files

Tags: android

I would like to store data in 1 phone and make it visible to another certain phone. 
Is that possible?
The best solution I could think of is to store the data in external sql database on a host and the other phone will be able to access to the database.
The problem is that I need a third party. I would like to do that two-sided.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like ... torrent. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is to use separate server for this as your phones may be allowed to access the network, but at the same time nobody from the network would be able to connect to the phones.

To clarify: direct communication is technically is possible as device can act as server without any problems, however if you talk about **general** use (i.e. in **any** network etc) then you will most likely end being blocked by i.e. carrier's firewalls or NAT etc. So if you want to make app that does so and both devices will work in the network you control, then no problem. But otherwise it will be simpler to use server.

Comment: So the answer is no?Two-sided communication is impossible?

Comment: see edited answer for clarification